# SVG printing in internet explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, svg

I have a web page where SVG is shown inline.

```
<body>
    <div>
           SVG goes here
    </div>
 </body>
```

There is lot of information in the SVG and it is hard to read when printed in a page.
so i want to provide scaling while printing the SVG.
for example when scaling is 200% it should print in 4 pages by scaling the SVG.
but when i do this by increasing the size of SVG to 200%, the IE9 print only two pages of left portion.
is there anyother way i can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up an `@media print` style that provides a different style with different SVG width/height styles for [printing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

The @media print rule could make additional areas appear to show additional data i.e. instead of making it bigger perhaps you could display 4 separate pieces of SVG data.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to print the page as a 2x2 grid of pages, then no, I don't think any browser supports that.